# How to save data streams in S3? aws-sdk-go example not working?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to persist a given stream of data to an S3 compatible storage.
The size is not known before the stream ends and can vary from 5MB to ~500GB.

I tried different possibilities but did not find a better solution than to implement sharding myself. My best guess is to make a buffer of a fixed size fill it with my stream and write it to the S3.
Is there a better solution? Maybe a way where this is transparent to me, without writing the whole stream to memory?

The aws-sdk-go readme has an example programm that takes data from stdin and writes it to S3: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go#using-the-go-sdk

When I try to pipe data in with a pipe `|` I get the following error:

`failed to upload object, SerializationError: failed to compute request body size
caused by: seek /dev/stdin: illegal seek`

Am I doing something wrong or is the example not working as I expect it to?

I although tried minio-go, with [PutObject()](https://github.com/xxorde/minio-steam-to-s3/blob/018b08b15b35ce528abc9af621bef28490fff67e/main.go) or [client.PutObjectStreaming()](https://github.com/xxorde/minio-steam-to-s3/blob/e74829acddc8f8693efc54da2d8d086d1a5e8a3f/main.go).
This is functional but consumes as much memory as the data to store.

1. Is there a better solution?
2. Is there a small example program that can pipe arbitrary data into S3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the sdk's [Uploader](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Uploader) to handle uploads of unknown size but you'll need to make the `os.Stdin` "unseekable" by wrapping it into an `io.Reader`. This is because the `Uploader`, while it requires only an `io.Reader` as the input body, under the hood it does a check to see whether the input body is also a `Seeker` and if it is, it does call `Seek` on it. And since `os.Stdin` is just an `*os.File` which implements the `Seeker` interface, by default, you would get the same error you got from `PutObjectWithContext`.

The `Uploader` also allows you to upload the data in chunks whose size you can configure and you can also configure how many of those chunks should be uploaded concurrently.

Here's a modified version of the linked example, stripped off of code that can remain unchanged.

```
package main

import (
    // ...
    "io"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

type reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (r *reader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return r.r.Read(p)
}

func main() {
    // ... parse flags

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess, func(u *s3manager.Uploader) {
        u.PartSize = 20 << 20 // 20MB
        // ... more configuration
    })

    // ... context stuff

    _, err := uploader.UploadWithContext(ctx, &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
        Body:   &reader{os.Stdin},
    })

    // ... handle error
}
```

As to whether this is a better solution than `minio-go` I do not know, you'll have to test that yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did some testing and get a constant memory usage of ~500MB no matter if I store 5GB or 25GB of data. This is far from perfect, but acceptable. :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. What part size are you using and how many concurrent uploads are you allowing?

Comment: I did not explicit set concurrent uploads and used your 20MB as PartSize. I just tried 256MB and it consumes ~2.1 GB memory. With PartSize =  5MB it consumes 132MB. I start to see a pattern here ;)

Comment: By default i think it does 5 concurrent uploads so at 20mb per part it should be 100mb? and at 256mb it should 1.2gb? but that's me assuming that nothing else is consuming memory...